# How to access a variable of a class created within another class, from outside either class

Tags: python, class, pyqt

I have a class whose attributes I need to access. The problem comes with the fact that the instance of this class is instantiated within another class.

Here is the class whose variable I wish to access (there is more to it, but this shows you how the class is created):

```
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, iconPathUnassigned, iconX, iconY, posX, posY, posA, posB, objName, labEdit, iconPathAssigned, iconPathPlaying, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent=parent) 
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.iconPathAssigned = iconPathAssigned
```

This class is then instantiated within another class:

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(591, 591)
        self.btn_a1 = Button("Python/LP_Proj/LP_Circle_Off.png", 49, 49, 30, 38, 41, 41, "btn_a1", self.lab_a1, "Python/LP_Proj/LP_Circle_Green.png", "Python/LP_Proj/LP_Circle_Red.png", self)
```

The class `Ui_Form` is created in the following way:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So, say I wanted to just print the `iconPathAssigned` variable of `btn_a1`after the line `ex.show()`, how would I do that? I have tried all sorts:

```
print Ui_Form.btn_a1.iconPathAssigned
print Form.btn_a1.iconPathAssigned
print btn_a1.iconPathAssigned
print QtGui.QWidget(Ui_Form.btn_a1.iconPathAssigned)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print ex.btn_a1.iconPathAssigned`

since `ex` is your form instance (as you know from the line `ex = Ui_Form()`)

Comment: Genius! It has been a long old day haha. Much appreciated!

Comment: I preferred your other answer ;)